# Yii2 ActiveQuery: is it possible to combine andWhere and orWhere?

Tags: yii2

Not sure if the title fully describes the problem, anyway here is the situation: suppose I have an ActiveQuery descendant class that looks like this:

```
class OrderQuery extends ActiveQuery
{
    public function expired() {
        $this->andWhere(['<=', 'order.expiresAt', date("Y-m-d H:i:s")]);
        return $this;
    }

    public function cancelled() {
        $this->andWhere(['NOT', ['order.cancelled' => null]]);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I'd like to add an additional method, **archived()**, to find orders that are **expired OR cancelled**.

```
public function archived() {
    $this->andWhere(["OR",
        ['<=', 'order.expiresAt', date("Y-m-d H:i:s")],
        ['NOT', ['order.cancelled' => null]],
    ]);
    return $this;
}
```

The method above works fine, but I wonder, is it possible to reuse the existing methods expired() and cancelled()
in the new archived() method?

---

**Or, in other words,** is it possible to combine andWhere and orWhere
somehow to make them work together like this:

```
// pseudocode, not a real code!
$this->orWhere([
    $this->andWhere([...]),
    $this->andWhere([...]),
]);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there is no straight way to join conditions of multiple queries. On GitHub there is already a [feature request](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/15563) for this, but it is not implemented yet.

Currently you may try 2 solutions:

1. If you don't want to repeat conditions, you may create helper for them:

   ```
   private function getExpiredContition() {
       return ['<=', 'order.expiresAt', date('Y-m-d H:i:s')];
   }

   private function getCancelledContition() {
       return ['NOT', ['order.cancelled' => null]];
   }

   public function expired() {
       return $this->andWhere($this->getExpiredContition());
   }

   public function cancelled() {
       return $this->andWhere($this->getCancelledContition());
   }

   public function archived() {
       return $this->andWhere([
           'OR',
           $this->getExpiredContition(),
           $this->getExpiredContition(),
       ]);
   }
   ```
2. You may try to access [`$where`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-querytrait#$where-detail) property directly and merge it in one query.

   ```
   public function archived() {
       return $this->andWhere([
           'OR',
           (new static())->cancelled()->where,
           (new static())->expired()->where,
       ]);
   }
   ```

Comment: the second answer is brilliant! I would never have thought that it is possible to write so smart yet simple

Answer (score 5):

```
$this->orWhere([
    $this->andWhere([...]),
    $this->andWhere([...]),
]);
```

I'm afraid there is no way to use `where()` functions inside another `where()` functions. Yii2 is simply not designed that way.. it would be possible if Yii2 `where()`, `orWhere()`, `andWhere()` functions received a Closures, like it do in `joinWith()`, `with()`, etc. methods (receiving a nested models Query in anonymous function).

You can put closures in Laravel's where conditions (off topic)

I guess, as a workaround you can create private methods and return those conditions in array format as follow:

```
class OrderQuery extends ActiveQuery
{
    private function conditionExpired() {
        return ['<=', 'order.expiresAt', date("Y-m-d H:i:s")];
    }

    private function conditionCancelled() {
        return ['NOT', ['order.cancelled' => null]];
    }

    public function expired() {
        $this->andWhere($this->conditionExpired());
        return $this;
    }

    public function cancelled() {
        $this->andWhere($this->conditionCancelled());
        return $this;
    }

    public function archived() {
        $this->andWhere(["OR",
            $this->conditionExpired(),
            $this->conditionCancelled(),
        ]);
        return $this;
    }
}
```